# With which version of ArcGIS (Desktop and Server) does MrSID Generation 4 (MG4™) work?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, layers, mrsid

I haven't really been able to find anything on LizardTech's site with those details or the difference between Generations but not compatibility with GIS systems.

Reference links - [Esri Supported raster dataset file formats](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm)

Comment: If you want to read MrSID generation 4, it can be readable at least since ArcGIS 10.3 as per help page: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/supported-raster-dataset-file-formats.htm. Search for MrSID and you will find it

Comment: I did see that and look through it as well. However, I'm not where there is mention of its readable since ArcGIS 10.3? I must have missed it. I do see at the top it shows ArcGIS 10.3, however I'm not sure that means it wasn't compatible with any earlier version? I'll add your link for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like ArcGIS started to support MrSID Version 4 from ArcGIS 10.1 as you can see in the help page: [ArcGIS 10.1: Supported raster dataset file formats](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000000q000000)

If you look at ArcGIS 10.0 and search for MrSID, you will not find MrSID Version 4 there:
[ArcGIS 10.0: Supported raster dataset file formats](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t0000000q000000)

Comment: @whyzar You are welcome :)